# Multiple div to one ajax page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I need to send id to a php file using jquery ajax

main.php

```
<div id="1">Click me 1</div>
<div id="2">Click me 2</div>
<div id="3">Click me 3</div>
<div id="4">Click me 4</div>
```

loaded_file.php

```
<?php
$_REQUEST['id'] //1, 2, 3 or 4
?>
```

Thanks for tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to send it like so:

**PHP File:**

```
<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];  

    // Do something with id such as insert to database

    $response = "Added id: " . $id;

    return print_r($response);
}
?>
```

**Html File:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.myDiv').click(function() {

      $.post("yourPhpFile.php", { id: $(this).attr('id') }, function(response) {
         alert(response);
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="1" class="myDiv">Click me 1</div>
<div id="2" class="myDiv">Click me 2</div>
<div id="3" class="myDiv">Click me 3</div>
<div id="4" class="myDiv">Click me 4</div>
```

Comment: Only one more request if it's possible. I would like to have a popup div for each content. with a relative and absolute positioning